# Ошибка aiogram 3.0.0b6

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

```
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import html
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters import Command, CommandObject
from datetime import datetime
from aiogram.types import ContentType

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token='BOT-TOKEN', parse_mode='HTML')
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(types.ContentType.TEXT)
async def extract_data(message: types.Message):
    data = {
        "url": "<N/A>",
        "email": "<N/A>",
        "code": "<N/A>"
    }
    entities = message.entities or []
    for item in entities:
        if item.type in data.keys():
            data[item.type] = item.extract(message.text)
        await message.reply(
            "Вот что я нашел:\n"
            f"URL: {html.quote(data['url'])}\n"
            f"E-mail: {html.quote(data['email'])}\n"
            f"Пароль: {html.quote(data['code'])}"
        )


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot, mylist=list[str])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Сама ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\inspect.py", line 1285, in getfullargspec
    sig = _signature_from_callable(func,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\inspect.py", line 2392, in _signature_from_callable
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))
TypeError: 'text' is not a callable object

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Lessons\aiogram\python-lesson\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    async def extract_data(message: types.Message):
  File "D:\Python Lessons\aiogram\python-lesson\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 127, in wrapper
    self.register(callback, *filters, flags=flags)
  File "D:\Python Lessons\aiogram\python-lesson\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 75, in register
    filters=[FilterObject(filter_) for filter_ in filters],
  File "D:\Python Lessons\aiogram\python-lesson\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 75, in <listcomp>
    filters=[FilterObject(filter_) for filter_ in filters],
  File "<string>", line 5, in __init__
  File "D:\Python Lessons\aiogram\python-lesson\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 71, in __post_init__
    super(FilterObject, self).__post_init__()
  File "D:\Python Lessons\aiogram\python-lesson\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 29, in __post_init__
    self.spec = inspect.getfullargspec(callback)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\inspect.py", line 1295, in getfullargspec
    raise TypeError('unsupported callable') from ex
TypeError: unsupported callable
```

Помогите новичку, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Aiogram ругается на твой фильтр - TYPES.CONTENTTYPE.TEXT. Он думает, что ты передал ему функцию, хотя то что ты ей дал функцией не является. Правильно здесь будет сделать так: `@dp.message(content_types=Types...)`. По край ней мере, в двойке это точно заработает, насчёт aiogram 3 - не уверен.

Comment: Либо(мне кажется даже лучше) использовать магические фильтры `dp.message(F.text)`

Answer (score 0):

То что у тебя на 14 строке замени с `@dp.message(types.ContentType.TEXT)` на `@dp.message_handler(Command("команда"))`

пример : /команда

Comment: Это не сработает, т.к. версия aiogram 3.0.0